# Do "Java Synchronized Methods" mean "threads"?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm confused about Synchronized Methods. Is like that threads,or synchronized methods have special properties then different from threads? I read that code segment and I think synchronized mean thread. Can someone explain the difference between thread with synchronized Methods? Of course,if they have difference.

```
synchronized method = monitor:
    class Account {
        private double balance;
        public Account (double initialDeposit) {
            balance = initialDeposit;
        }
        public synchronized double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
        public synchronized void deposit(double amount) {
            balance += amount;
        }
        public synchronized void withdraw(double amount) {
            balance -= amount;
        }
        }
```

Comment: You should start by reading a tutorial, for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ Once you have done that you will be able to ask a more targeted question (if you still have one).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: My questions always earn minus point. I don't know why am I rewarded that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized` method means a method, to enter which thread has to obtain monitor lock for `this` object, where method belongs to, for instance methods, and `.class` object for `static` methods.

`synchronized` block is actually the same except for the point that you specify the object which monitor needs to be acquired explicitly and you can specify block boundaries as you wish;

`Thread` (very basically) is a sequence of instructions that can be executed in parallel with other threads;

So the answer to your question is no, **synchronized method** and **thread** are different, although often going together concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your satisfying answer. I need to read more things about java. I am a beginner on Java until 2 years.It's very embarrassing for me...

Answer (score 3):

No. Synchronization is a *technique* to tackle `thread interference` and `memory consistency errors`two issues related to communication between various threads.

In the code you provided only **one** thread a time can use `getBalance()`, `withdraw()` and `deposit()` methods.

Highly suggest you read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html